# Table margin top / bottom only (without CSS)

Tags: html, html-table, margin, cellspacing

I am working on a Newsletter and am therefore pretty much forced to use tables.

According to [this source](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), "margin-top" and "margin-bottom" is not supported by Outlook 2007/10/13. Since Outlook is a requirement for my Newsletter, I need a workaround.

Obviously there's "cellspacing", I however do sometimes want to apply margin-top/bottom without left/right. How can this be achieved?

Comment: If you don't want to use CSS, you may have to add blank rows on the to and bottom with a dummy image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve this problem to my satisfaction by adding empty rows (without images) with a fixed height. This actually seems to be working fine with quite a lot email clients.

Answer (score 1):

If you needed pixel perfect height I would pad an empty cell with a spacer (clear 1px x 1px gif).

Comment: won't this approach break if image blocking is turned on?

Comment: Its really the only viable alternative. If images are turned off it might look a bit odd, the other alternative is to use breaking spaces in the empty rows but then (without CSS) you wont have full control of the height of the element.